# How to access HttpConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter for configuration?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, configuration, asp.net-web-api2

Most of the time I use something like the following to access JsonFormatter in my Web API projects.

`var xxx = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;`

*(Where `config` is an instance of `HttpConfiguration`.)* However, I have seen some others code that grabs it like this:

`var xxx = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();`

Is there any possible reasoning behind choosing the second example over the first? Perhaps the `JsonFormatter` property wasn't available at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter` internally [does almost the same thing](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/MediaTypeFormatterCollection.cs#56):

```
public JsonMediaTypeFormatter JsonFormatter
{
    get { return Items.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault(); }
}
```

I believe the only difference in the code you provided is that if for any reason `HttpConfig.Formatters` property doesn't have any `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` the call to `JsonFormatter` will return `null`, while `config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();` will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that I probably should have spent a minute opening ILSpy rather than two minutes making this post :)